# I'm using JDA 4.1.1_110 and my Discord Bot is unable to send message in the channel

Tags: java, discord, chatbot

I'm using JDA 4.1.1_110, here is my code, i have used ListenerAdapter to listen to event,

```
    import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
    import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

    public class Commander extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onMessageReceieved(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(EmbedBot.prefix+"info")) {
            event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Hello").queue();
        }
```

I have also registered this class in my bot's main class,

```
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;

public class EmbedBot {
public static JDA jda;
public static String prefix = "$";
public static void main(String args[]) throws LoginException {
jda = new 
JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken("the token i can't show").build();
jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.listening("Rohan"));
jda.addEventListener(new Commander());
   }
}
```

Now on typing "$info" on #general channel in my Test Server, I am not getting any response from the bot, the bot shows all the features like Online Status and the "Listening to Rohan" activity but it isn't sending any message. I have made sure that the bot has all permissions to send messages and I have checked the #general channel's role permissions too. The bot has all the permissions to send messages but it isn't sending when i type "$info".

Comment: You didn't spell the method name you're overriding from ListenerAdapter properly. Its "onMessageReceived".

Comment: @Minn Not understood, where have i spelled wrong?

Comment: omg so silly of a mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write about the onMessageReceieved Event @Override. I'm not sure..

Otherwise, maybe see if the bot has the permissions

Answer (score 0):

You are using a deprecated class.

Use this syntax to initialize:

```java
JDA jda=JDABuilder.createDefault("ur token").addEventListeners(new Commander()).build();
```

And in commander use onGuildMessageReceived.